# High number of threads created on Java consumer than Scala consumer in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In java consumer, Kafka coordinator thread and consumer thread are for each and every consumer.  Due to that thread count is very high compared to previous kafka scala version.

Previously, I used kafka 0.10.0 version for queueing purpose. Now,I decide to upgrade kafka version to 2.8. While trying to upgrade, thread count is higher for 2.8.0 version consumer than 0.10.0 version when consuming. In kafka 0.10.0, it is scala consumer but in kafka 2.8.0, consumer is written in Java.

I created a consumer group with 15 consumers in scala consumer(kafka version 0.10.0). Here, 23 threads are created (ConsumerFetcherThread,LeaderFinderThread,Watcher-Executor,EventThread, etc,).   But, when I try to create the consumer group with 15 consumers in java consumer (kafka version 2.8.0), 31 threads are created.  When I increase consumer group, thread count will be very high.

For java consumer, 2 threads are created for each consumer (KafkaCoordinatorHeartbeatThread,ConsumerThread) so that thread count is higher than scala consumer.

Is this we are missing anything?
If not, then how can I reduce coordinator thread count ?

Comment: From your question, it seems like you are running 15 consumers in your consumer group as a single process (and hence 31 threads). Can you explain the reasoning behind this setup? Also, why do you want to increase the number of consumers in the process?

Comment: For a topic with 5 partitions and consumer per partition case:

Java Consumer : 5 consumer thread + 5 hearbeat thread + 1 Admin client thread = 11 Threads
Scala Consumer : 5 consumer thread + 3 Fetcher thread + 3 other threads - 11 Threads.

"For a topic with 10 partitions and consumer per partition case"

Java Consumer : 10 consumer thread + 10 hearbeat thread + 1 Admin client thread = 21 Threads
Scala Consumer : 10 consumer thread + 3 Fetcher thread + 3 other threads - 16 Threads

For 15 partitions, consumer and heart beat thread will increase for java consumers